# Como somar strtotime com variável de dias

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte código

```
$data_final = date('Y-m-d'); // Data atual
$data_inicial='1997-10-07'; // Data para comparar
$diferenca = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_inicial);
$dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24)); //Peguei a quantidade de dias no calculo da data

AQUI ME VEM A DÚVIDA
$date1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_inicial.'+ 8928 days'));
```

na variável acima eu quero colocar no lugar do 8928 a variável $dias para que o strtotime some o valor que contem na variável $dias, assim eu irei obter a data que preciso na variável $date1

Um exemplo do que preciso, porém errado para vocês entenderem é esse:

```
$date1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_inicial.'+ $dias days'));
```

Comment: Consegui rs... Um amigo no facebook me ajudou. Ficou da seguinte forma:

`$date1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_inicial . ' + ' . $dias . 'days'));`

Comment: Se usar aspas duplas também funciona, pois aí é feita a interpolação das variáveis: `$date1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("$data_inicial + $dias days"));`

Comment: Entendi, fica mais limpo tbm

Comment: Não é mais fácil trabalhar com classe [`A classe DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php)? Veja o exemplo:   https://ideone.com/oR5kLm

Comment: Outro detalhe é que não precisa dessa volta toda para obter o timestamp atual, poderia usar a função `time`, ou seja: `$diferenca = time() - strtotime($data_inicial);` - a diferença é que como no seu caso está usando `strtotime` com uma string que tem apenas ano, mês e dia, o horário é setado para meia-noite, enquanto `time` considera o horário atual também (mas como vc arredonda para a quantidade de dias, não deve dar diferença)